# Как сделать выравнивание текста в ячейке таблицы

Tags: html, css

Как сделать выравнивание текста в ячейке, что бы крайние левые буквы каждой строки были на одном уровне, при этом текст находился по центру ячейки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. сейчас у меня текст по середине ячейки, но все строки как бы "пляшут", а я хочу чтоб были слева в ровень

Comment: не [padding-left](http://htmlbook.ru/css/padding-left)?

Comment: оно, спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно обернуть строки инлайн блоком. И переопределить в нем выравнивание текста.

```css
td{border: 1px solid grey; width: 250px; text-align: center;}
.center{display: inline-block; text-align: left;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="center">
        <div>1111111</div>
        <div>222</div>
        <div>33333333333</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите с css text-align: left; padding-left: 30%(значение подкрутите в отладчике чтобы получилось как хочется.);